# Kafka Streams stops processing after 300 seconds

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I try to process data that is already placed in Kafka cluster with use of Kafka Streams application (no data is added to Kafka during processing), both have version 0.10.2.1. Application outputs the data with use of `writeAsText` function.

When application is run in cluster (by running jars on different machines specifying different client ids) everything goes smooth until 300th second of processing - at this moment it stops - no further data is outputted and no exception is thrown. I tried numerous times and result is always the same. I know for sure that there is still remaining data in the cluster to process. When only one instance of application is run, data is processed properly.

After some analysis I found different settings that could help. In the application I set:
`properties.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 1800000);
 properties.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 1800001);
 properties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1800000);`

Additionaly, each instance of Kafka server has following line in config:
`group.max.session.timeout.ms=1800001`

Unfortunately, these didn't help.

Comment: You should have a look at the log output of your Kafka Streams application so get some more insight what is happening. It's unclear at the moment what might be the root cause. Btw: I would highly recommend to upgrade you application to use Kafka 0.11 -- note, you can update your application without broker upgrade -- 0.11 Streams API is backward compatible to 0.10.1 and 0.10.2 brokers: cf http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/upgrade-guide.html#compatibility)